# String substitution where the old and new strings are in columns

Tags: r, string, replace

Let´s say you have the following DataFrame:

```
DF <- as.data.frame(cbind(c("Aa1","aB1","aA1"),c("A","B","A"),c("D","F","G")))
colnames(DF)[1] <- "State1"
colnames(DF)[2] <- "StringToBeReplaced"
colnames(DF)[3] <- "StringToTakeItsPlace"
```

which should yield

```
  State1 StringToBeReplaced StringToTakeItsPlace
1    Aa1                  A                    D
2    aB1                  B                    F
3    aA1                  A                    G
```

The names kind of give my objective away: I want to replace the strings occurring in State1, from "StringToBeReplaced"
to "StringToTakeItsPlace".

Is there any way to obtain a new column that is like State1 in all aspects, except that the string substitution has been carried out?
In other words, the desired output is

```
  State1 StringToBeReplaced StringToTakeItsPlace  State2
1    Aa1                  A                    D   Da1
2    aB1                  B                    F   aF1
3    aA1                  A                    G   aG1
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mapply` with `gsub`:

```
transform(DF, 
  State2 = mapply(gsub, StringToBeReplaced, StringToTakeItsPlace, State1, fixed = TRUE))
```

giving:

```
  State1 StringToBeReplaced StringToTakeItsPlace State2
1    Aa1                  A                    D    Da1
2    aB1                  B                    F    aF1
3    aA1                  A                    G    aG1
```

or with dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)

DF %>%
 rowwise() %>%
 mutate(State2 = gsub(StringToBeReplaced, StringToTakeItsPlace, State1, fixed = TRUE)) %>%
 ungroup
```

Comment: Cool! It works like a charm :) I knew the solution would have to involve gsub coupled with a l/s/m apply family type function, but was unsure of how going about it, and all my tries amounted to nothing, your solution nails it :) Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Using `stringr` and `tidyverse`

```
Library(tidyverse)

DF <- tibble(
  State1 = c("Aa1","aB1","aA1"),
  StringToBeReplaced = c("A","B","A"),
  StringToTakeItsPlace=c("D","F","G") 
)

  DF %>% 
  mutate(State2 = str_replace(State1, 
                                StringToBeReplaced, 
                                StringToTakeItsPlace ))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>   State1 StringToBeReplaced StringToTakeItsPlace State2
#>   <chr>  <chr>              <chr>                <chr>   
#> 1 Aa1    A                  D                    Da1     
#> 2 aB1    B                  F                    aF1     
#> 3 aA1    A                  G                    aG1

Created on 2018-03-03 by the reprex package (v0.2.0).
```